# apache spark: local[K] master URL - job gets stuck

Tags: scala, sbt, apache-spark

I am using apache spark 0.8.0 to process a large data file and perform some basic `.map` and `.reduceByKey` operations on the `RDD`.

Since I am using a single machine with multiple processors, I mention `local[8]` in the Master URL field while creating `SparkContext`

```
val sc = new SparkContext("local[8]", "Tower-Aggs", SPARK_HOME )
```

But whenever I mention multiple processors, the job gets stuck (pauses/halts) randomly. There is no definite place where it gets stuck, its just random. Sometimes it won't happen at all. I am not sure if it continues after that but it gets stuck for a long time after which I abort the job.

But when I just use `local` in place of `local[8]`, the job runs seamlessly without getting stuck ever.

```
val sc = new SparkContext("local", "Tower-Aggs", SPARK_HOME )
```

I am not able to understand where is the problem.

I am using `Scala 2.9.3` and `sbt` to build and run the application

Comment: I am seeing the same issue with Spark 1.4.1. @Vijay did you get around this?

Comment: I found assigning more processes (k) than the number of logical cores you have on your machines often caused this problem. Trying giving a smaller number. @YohanLiyanage

Comment: Thanks @Vijay. I'll look into that.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using spark 1.0.0 and met the same problem: if a function passed to a transformation or action wait/loop indefinitely, then spark won't wake it or terminate/retry it by default, in which case you can kill the task.

However, a recent feature (speculative task) allows spark to start replicated tasks if a few tasks take much longer than average running time of their peers. This can be enabled and configured in the following config properties:

- spark.speculation false    If set to "true", performs speculative execution of tasks. This means if one or more tasks are running slowly in a stage, they will be re-launched.
- spark.speculation.interval    100  How often Spark will check for tasks to speculate, in milliseconds.
- spark.speculation.quantile    0.75     Percentage of tasks which must be complete before speculation is enabled for a particular stage.
- spark.speculation.multiplier  1.5  How many times slower a task is than the median to be considered for speculation.

(source: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html)

Comment: I'm seeing my `reduceByKey` hang before any tasks get completed at all (1.0.0) so for me spec' exec' will not work.